# how to implement search on actionbar with menu items

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I am working on Android `ICS` and using `ActionBar` with tabs

I have 4 item in my `ActionBar`.

1. Home logo
2. Spinner item 1
3. Spinner Item 2
4. Search Icon

the code is as follows of :

**main_layout**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_spinner_1" 
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_spinner_2" 
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

If I don't put "always" for the `spinner`, than only one `spinner` is shown.
and if I put always for both `spinners`, than on clicking the search icon..
the full `ActionBar` is not used for entering search query.
the `Spinners` remain as it is and the `SearchView` is very small only replacing the search icon.

How can I implement a full `ActionBar` search view and and when I click close the spinners must be displayed.! ?